# Retrieve .txt from server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate 5 separate edittext boxes (with a single button click) with the contents of 5 separate .txt files stored on a server.
I can populate the first edittext with the code below

```
package fromserver.lou.readfromweb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 String TextFileURL = "http://saturn.glyndwr.ac.uk/n3rds/Receipt.txt" ;
    TextView textView ;
    Button button ;
    URL url ;
    String TextHolder = "" , TextHolder2 = "";
    BufferedReader bufferReader ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new GetNotePadFileFromServer().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    public class GetNotePadFileFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                url = new URL(TextFileURL);

                bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    TextHolder += TextHolder2;
                }
                bufferReader.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
                TextHolder = malformedURLException.toString();

            } catch (IOException iOException) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                iOException.printStackTrace();

                TextHolder = iOException.toString();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void finalTextHolder) {

            textView.setText(TextHolder);

            super.onPostExecute(finalTextHolder);
        }

    }



}
```

I thought maybe if I could take the code out of the main activity somehow and have a spearate class and do this five times for each edittext it might work but I couldnt do it. I tried to separate the class as below:

```
    package fromserver.lou.readfromweb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new GetNotePadFileFromServer().execute();

            }
        });

    }




}
```

and made a new class:

```
package fromserver.lou.readfromweb;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by lou on 27/04/2017.
 */



public class GetNotePadFileFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    URL url ;
    String TextHolder = "" , TextHolder2 = "";
    BufferedReader bufferReader ;
    String TextFileURL = "http://saturn.glyndwr.ac.uk/n3rds/Receipt.txt" ;
    TextView textView ;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            url = new URL(TextFileURL);

            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                TextHolder += TextHolder2;
            }
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder = malformedURLException.toString();

        } catch (IOException iOException) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            iOException.printStackTrace();

            TextHolder = iOException.toString();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void finalTextHolder) {

        textView.setText(TextHolder);

        super.onPostExecute(finalTextHolder);
    }

}
```

But in the mainactivity textView stays red and it says cannot resolve symbol textview.

I was going to do this 5 times and just change each class slightly to point to the different URLs and separate edittext boxes and also I assume I will have to add something to the on click listener in the main activity to call the new classes.

Comment: What does it mean "I couldn't do it"? Did you get an error? What did you try exactly? Also, post only the relevant code to your problem. I doubt the xml layout is necessary to retrieve a file from server...

Comment: `was going to do this 5 times and just change each class slightly to point to the different url's and serapate edittext boxes ` That would be a bad design. One will not make a copy of a class or function only if the url is different. Or a textview. Use one class and supply url and view in the parameters of the constructor. Make your async task a private class in your activity. Makes all much simpler. Than instantiate the task five times with different parameters.

Comment: new GetNotePadFileFromServer(url1, R.id.textView1).execute(); new GetNotePadFileFromServer(url2, R.id.textView2).execute(); And so on.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help.